# What is setAttribute arguments in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, setattribute

can someone please explain to me what is the setAttribute arguments here? I know only that .png is the extension of the image that I will include later in my code.

```
function setImg(dieImg)
{
  var value = Math.floor( 1 + Math.random()*6);
  dieImg.setAttribute( "src" , "die" + value + 
  dieImg.setAttribute( "alt" , "die Image with " + value + "spot(s)");
}
```

Comment: Please save everyone some time by using https://jshint.com. You probably wouldn't even bother to post here if you debugged it yourself (or at least be a little more prepared before posting).

Comment: Typo: `scr` should be `src`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setImg(dieImg) { var value = Math.floor( 1 + Math.random()*6); dieImg.setAttribute( "scr" , "die" + value +  dieImg.setAttribute( "alt" , "die Image with " + value + "spot(s)"); }
```

First of all, we need to know about  tag.
It has several attributes for showing and manipulating image.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

src ( you miswritten) attribute is for indicating the source of image so that it should be url of the source.

alt attribute is for alternative string if the given image with url doesn't exist.

For example,

```
 <img src="https://example.com/image_path.png" alt="Die with....">
```

setAttribute() function is to add these attribute programmatically.

So I think you miswritten the code

```
function setImg(dieImg) { var value = Math.floor( 1 + Math.random()*6); dieImg.setAttribute( "scr" , "https://example.com/image_path.png" );
dieImg.setAttribute( "alt" , "die Image with " + value + "spot(s)"); }
```

Hope it will be helpful

Comment: Thank u , I really appreciate your kind and helpful comment !

Answer (score 0):

The `setAttribute()` is a JavaScript method that sets the value of an [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) on the specified element. If the attribute already exists, the value is updated; otherwise a new attribute is added with the specified name and value.

Syntax: `setAttribute(name, value)`

For example, you can use the `setAttribute()` method to change the `id` attribute on a button, or even to change the content of the `style` attribute of any element:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.setAttribute("id", "anotherButtonID");
button.setAttribute("style", "background-color: blue; color: red");
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Hello World</button>
```

You can find more documentation on the `setAttribute()` method on the MDN WebDocs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

So, getting back to your question, in this case, with the first parameter, you are changing the `src` attribute of your image (which specifies the source url). For the second parameter, this code is using string concatenation to pass in the new url source for the image (for example `"Hello" + " " + "world!"` will result in "Hello world!".

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your explanation!